# Microsoft Workflow Manager. How to configure and use debug traces?

Tags: workflow

There is a table named [DebugTraces] in [WFInstanceManagementDB] database and the WorkflowManagementClient class in Microsoft.Workflow.Client.dll which provides a method GetDebugTraces(). The question is how should I configure wf manager to get writing debug traces available.

Thank you in advance.